# Getting the output from first command to exit in Bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

Suppose I have a Bash script that takes one parameter (ie. port number) and performs some logic with either outcome

1. hangs for 1 second and exits with timeout error, or
2. succeeds within milliseconds and outputs a message such as "ON" or "OFF".

One way to find the parameter that results in outcome 2 would be run the script over loop on the possible values of the parameter, but this would take N seconds to find the parameter. Assume the output is consistent for simplicity (ie. if more than one instance results in outcome 2,  their output message is the same).

Is there a way to run the N instances of the Bash script at the same time (within reasonable milliseconds) with each possible value of the parameter, and get the output message from the instance that finished fastest? This would result in getting the output in under 1 second.

Comment: If you only want a boolean output, and have a bash release new enough to support `wait -n`, it would be much easier to collect the first *exit status* rather than the first *output*. Can you have your program exit with a different status for each possible result?

Comment: ...not that it can't happen the other way as well. I think we already have a Q&A entry here on the site describing how to use a named FIFO to return output as it becomes available.

Comment: i don't have a concrete idea. however, depending on how large N is, gnu-parallel should be the right tool to go.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, ...you *could* use it, but you could also use `xargs -P` and have a much smaller, simpler (easier to read and understand) codebase behind that implementation. One that doesn't do the work of enforcing collated outputs, granted, but "ON" and "OFF" are short enough to not be split into multiple writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a reproducer, let's first create a function that behaves akin to your command:

```
try_or_wait() {
  local argument=$1  # doesn't really matter for our purposes
  if (( RANDOM % 10 == 0 )); then   # 10% return a result immediately
    if (( (RANDOM + argument) % 2 == 0 )); then
      echo ON
    else
      echo OFF
    fi
  else                              # 90% hang, and then fail
    sleep 10
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

...so, how can we use this?

```
declare -a pids=( )
mkfifo out.fifo

# start 20 processes, passing your port number to each
for ((i=0; i<20; ++i)); do
  try_or_wait "$1" >out.fifo & pids+=( "$!" )
done

# read one result
read result <out.fifo

# kill all the remaining children
kill "${pids[@]}"

echo "Got the result: $result"
```

---

Not that this is the only approach. To have GNU `xargs` do the work of spawning subprocesses for you:

```
export -f try_or_wait  # export shell functions so child processes can run it

read -r result < <(
  for ((i=0; i<20; ++i)); do
    printf '%s\0' "$1"
  done | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 20 bash -c 'try_or_wait "$@"' _
)
```

---

Note that the above is safe because each instance does its writes all at once -- a single `echo`, short enough for the entire output to fit into a single syscall. If each instance of your program may have enough output to require multiple syscalls (or output split over multiple writes), you may require a tool that can perform collation for you instead.

Comment: @Gerald, thank you for the fix; no need to put edit history in visible text -- it's all there behind the "edited <at some prior time>" link.

Comment: `try_or_wait "$1" >out.fifo &` invites a race condition if two processes prints at exactly the same time.

Comment: @OleTange, only if what they're printing doesn't fit into one syscall; with `O_APPEND`, each individual write is guaranteed to remain atomic. `echo ON` and `echo OFF` are individual writes with nice, short strings. If we had `printf 'O'; printf 'F'; printf 'F'; printf '\n'`, then yes, this would be unsafe.

Comment: Yep, I would put that comment in your solution, so people are aware that it is not a general solution, but it only works under those circumstances.

Comment: Also the solution seems to not kill grandchildren: E.g. insert `(sleep 100 &)` before `sleep 10`. This limitation should probably also be mentioned.

Comment: I've amended with an appropriate cautionary note re: safety being limited to programs doing a single write. I understand that it's unsafe to risk all writers being closed at the same time, but I really don't like the `(sleep 100 &)` approach -- it strikes me as really exceptionally wasteful; I'm more inclined to have the parent process itself hold that FD open.

Comment: The `(sleep 100 &)` is a simple example of a grand child. It could be anything started as a child by `try_or_wait`. If you do not explicitly kill grand children, then how do you expect they will die?

Comment: @OleTange, ahh, I see. Why would one expect there to be grandchildren? Which is to say -- if the OP's program makes trouble, figuring out how to clean that trouble up should reasonably be the scope of a separate question.

Comment: (In terms of techniques for the cleanup, I'm a fan of `fuser -k` to kill any process that still has the FIFO open... but I don't see that as reasonably in-scope for this question).

Comment: `Why would one expect there to be grandchildren?` Because OP does not say there will _not_ be that. Otherwise you might explicitly mention that your solution does _not_ work correctly if that is the case.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in handling the general case wherever it might be reasonably expected for one to do so. However, software that *explicitly detaches* is taking intentional action to separate itself from its parent processes, and I don't consider it reasonable to defeat such explicit actions without explicit intent (and a damned good reason). For all we know it's reasonable and intentional to leave such children behind -- consider tools like WINE, which leave subprocesses around which can and should shut themselves down gracefully after the parent processes which launched them have exited.

Comment: ...which is to say -- if program A starts program B, and program B leaves behind detached children, it's program B's responsibility, not program A's, to ensure that they gracefully exit. Any other division of responsibility prevents those children from being reliably allowed to do their own cleanup -- releasing shared memory, flushing data to disk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
try_or_wait() {
  local argument=$1  # doesn't really matter for our purposes
  if (( RANDOM % 10 == 0 )); then   # 10% return a result immediately
    if (( (RANDOM + argument) % 2 == 0 )); then
      echo ON
    else
      echo OFF
    fi
  else                              # 90% hang, and then fail
    # Example showing child process having further child processes
    # These should all be killed if try_or_wait is killed
    sleep 97 &
    ( ( (sleep 100 &); sleep 99 &); sleep 98 &)
    sleep 10
    exit 1
  fi
}

export -f try_or_wait
seq 100 | parallel -j0 --halt now,done=1 try_or_wait
```

It deals correctly by killing the grand children of `try_or_wait` and will also act correctly if the output of `try_or_wait` outputs more data than what fits in a single syscall (For more than you ever wanted to learn on this issue see: https://catern.com/posts/pipes.html).